# two phase commit protocol with Transaction Manager

Tags: transactions, transactionmanager

Suppose there are two resources in a single transactions. Two phase commit protocol is being used.During phase 1 both the resources acknowledge that they are ready.Now in phase 2 the first resource throws exception.In this scenario should Transaction Manager even try to commit second resource ?